# Custom View without using fully qualified class name in XML

Tags: android

I thought I read somewhere that you can set up your custom view classes in a way so that you don't need to reference them in your XML by the fully qualified class name. However, I can't find anything about this anymore.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own `LayoutInflater` and give that to System's `LayoutInflator` via `setFactory()` or `setFactory2()`. Your `LayoutInflator`'s will be called first, and it's here you can just inflate your own `View` classes just by their name (as your `LayoutInflator` will use the package name you tell it to).