# Using custom Views in XML without using fully-qualified name

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

My question is about Android/Java.

How can I call my custom view with a name such as

```
<input>
```

instead of

```
<org.javaforum.input>
```

without adding anything in the MainActivity.java?

I already read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17478278/16627950

But there I must add something in MainActivity.java.

I also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30066376/16627950

But I don't know where do the variables `mInflator` and `mPrefix` come from.

I also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13316335/16627950

But I don't know what are the programmatically steps to do so.

So how can I hook into the layout inflation in code, and handle instantiating my class for that tag myself?

Comment: Have you tried: [Is it possible to shorten custom view names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31670962/295004)

Answer (score 1):

mInflator and mPrefix, are custom properties declared at the top of the activity class, nothing special, in order to implement the custom layout you have to call:

```
val myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
            .cloneInContext(this)
        myInflater.factory2 = MyLayoutInflater()
```

This from your onCreate method of the activity, I think that is not possible to add a factory without tounching the activity code